# Не виден picterbox на форме?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
```

Ругается на picturebox1 - хотя на форме он есть.
Во время выполнения NullReferenceException

Comment: ну это гадание на кофейной гуще. уверен, что там где-нибудь банальная опечатка, как например в заголовке этого вопроса `picterbox`..... без кода, на который можно глянуть, без хоть какого-то вялого скрина можно закрывать

Comment: Это смотря от того, где находится ваша строка. Может, она до инициализации?

Comment: Если я выложу код на GitHub Вы не будите против помочь?

Comment: Если это не противоречит правилам SO...

Comment: Она в конструкторе

Comment: Все, исправил  - ошибка была в том, что   InitializeComponent(); была после